# Get index of list items

Tags: java, list

I have a list of Strings, and i need to output index of it:

```
list.add("I");//1
list.add("have");//2
list.add("an");//3
list.add("apple");//4
list.add("I");//5
list.add("love");//6
list.add("apple");//7
```

and output must be like this:

```
I: 1, 5
```

i've try this code, but it shows only first index, like this

```
I: 1,1;
```

My code is here:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String selectableWord = "I";
  for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
            if (selectableWord.equals(word.get(i))){
                sb.append(word.indexOf(word.get(i))).append(", ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(selectableWord + "  " + sb.toString());
    }
```

Comment: What does " it doesn't work" mean?  Your code is aware that the first index is `0` not `1` so you should either expect `I: 0, 4` or you should add `+1` to the index before appending it to the string.

Comment: Something like `sb.append(i).append(", ");` ? Anyway, shouldn't the index start from 0?

Comment: @PeterLawrey i've edit desrciption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes begin with `0` and not with `1`. So you need to change this line:

```
sb.append(word.indexOf(word.get(i))).append(", ");
```

to

```
sb.append(word.indexOf(word.get(i))+1).append(", ");
```

Moreover, `indexOf` returns the **first index**. So, even when you test "I" for second time, you get the first index, i.e. 0.

So you need to change the line to:

```
sb.append(i+1).append(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this line

```
sb.append(word.indexOf(word.get(i))).append(", ");
```

to this

```
sb.append(i+1).append(", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection.index returns the first index. If you want to search from a given point to avoid duplicates, you need to provide where to search from.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String selectableWord = "I";
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    if (selectableWord.equals(word.get(i)))
        sb.append(word.indexOf(word.get(i), i) + 1).append(", ");
System.out.println(selectableWord + "  " + sb.toString());
```

Or you can use the index to do the search.

```
for (int i = 0; (i = word.indexOf(selectableWord, i)) >= 0; i++)
     sb.append(i + 1).append(", ");
```

Or you could use the index you have already.

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    if (selectableWord.equals(word.get(i)))
        sb.append(i + 1).append(", ");
```

Or using the Streams API

```
String list = IntStream.range(0, words.length())
                       .filter(i -> words.get(i).equals(selectableWord))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```